# Only extracted data from first page is saved in the csv file (Scrapy, Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, save, extract

I am scraping a website, with several pages (attained with next button (Selenium)), each including 20 job offers. With a callback function I'm getting detail information from each offer.

The problem: In a csv output only up to the 20 jobs from the first page are saved. The code opens chromebrowser and jumps from page to page correctly, but does not extract more data.

It seems nobody else has ever had this problem but I have no idea what to do here. Any advice?

Terminal:

[image]

The code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep


class GetdataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'getdata'
    allowed_domains = ['workpool-jobs.ch']
    start_urls = ['https://www.workpool-jobs.ch/recht-jobs']

def parse(self, response):
    url = 'https://www.workpool-jobs.ch/recht-jobs'
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/xxx/chromedriver')
    self.driver.maximize_window() # For maximizing window
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(10) # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds
    self.driver.get(url)

    while True:

        sleep(3)
        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        single_joboffer = sel.xpath(".//p[@class='inserattitel h2 mt-0']/a/@href")
        for joboffer in single_joboffer:
            url1 = response.urljoin(joboffer.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url1, callback = self.parse_dir_contents)

        element = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.container-fluid.main-container.bg-white.py-5 > section.maincontent.row > div > nav:nth-child(11) > ul > li:nth-last-child(2) > a")
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,4000)","", element)
        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        sleep(3)
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.container-fluid.main-container.bg-white.py-5 > section.maincontent.row > div > nav:nth-child(11) > ul > li:nth-last-child(2) > a").click()
    
    self.driver.close()

def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    single_info = response.xpath(".//*[@class='col-12 col-md mr-md-3 mr-xl-5']")

    for info in single_info:
        info_Titel = info.xpath(".//article/h1[@class='inserattitel']/text()").extract_first()
        info_Berufsfelder = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-top-grau']/p/text()").extract()
        info_Arbeitspensum = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[1]/text()").extract_first()
        info_Anstellungsverhältnis = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[2]/text()").extract_first()
        info_Arbeitsort = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[4]/a/text()").extract()
        info_VerfügbarAb = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[5]/text()").extract()
        info_Kompetenzenqualifikation = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-7']/dl[2]/dd/text()").extract_first()
        info_Aufgabengebiet = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][1]//*[self::p or self::li]").extract()
        info_Erwartungen = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][2]/ul/li[descendant-or-self::text()]").extract()
        info_WirBietenIhnen = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][3]/ul/li[descendant-or-self::text()]").extract()
        info_Publikationsdatum = info.xpath(".//article/footer[@class='inseratfooter']/p[1]/strong/text()").extract_first()

        yield {'Titel': info_Titel,
        'Berufsfelder': info_Berufsfelder,
        'Arbeitspensum': info_Arbeitspensum,
        'Anstellungsverhältnis': info_Anstellungsverhältnis,
        'Arbeitsort': info_Arbeitsort,
        'VerfügbarAb': info_VerfügbarAb,
        'Kompetenzenqualifikation': info_Kompetenzenqualifikation,
        'Aufgabengebiet': info_Aufgabengebiet,
        'Erwartungen': info_Erwartungen,
        'WirBietenIhnen': info_WirBietenIhnen,
        'Publikationsdatum': info_Publikationsdatum}
```

Answer (score 1):

try replacing

url1 = response.urljoin(joboffer.extract())

with

url1 = response.urljoin(joboffer.get())

Extract gets all of them*

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make my code working. I started my project again without selenium and only scrapy. If anyone has the same problem in the future, maybe my code below helps you as well:

```
import scrapy
from random import randint
from time import sleep


class WorkpoolJobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "getdata"
page_number = 2
allowed_domains = ["workpool-jobs.ch"]
start_urls = ["https://www.workpool-jobs.ch/recht-jobs"]

def parse(self, response):
    SET_SELECTOR = "//p[@class='inserattitel h2 mt-0']/a/@href"
    for joboffer in response.xpath(SET_SELECTOR):
        url1 = response.urljoin(joboffer.get())
        yield scrapy.Request(url1, callback = self.parse_dir_contents)

    next_page = "https://www.workpool-jobs.ch/recht-jobs?seite=" + str(WorkpoolJobsSpider.page_number)
    sleep(randint(5,10))
    if WorkpoolJobsSpider.page_number < 27:
        WorkpoolJobsSpider.page_number += 1
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    single_info = response.xpath(".//*[@class='col-12 col-md mr-md-3 mr-xl-5']")

    for info in single_info:
        info_Titel = info.xpath(".//article/h1[@class='inserattitel']/text()").extract_first()
        info_Berufsfelder = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-top-grau']/p/text()").extract()
        info_Arbeitspensum = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[1]/text()").extract_first()
        info_Anstellungsverhältnis = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[2]/text()").extract_first()
        info_Arbeitsort = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[4]/a/text()").extract()
        info_VerfügbarAb = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5']/dl/dd[5]/text()").extract()
        info_Kompetenzenqualifikation = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='row bg-hellstblau']/div[@class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-7']/dl[2]/dd/text()").extract_first()
        info_Aufgabengebiet = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][1]//*[self::p or self::li]").extract()
        info_Erwartungen = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][2]/ul/li[descendant-or-self::text()]").extract()
        info_WirBietenIhnen = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][3]/ul/li[descendant-or-self::text()]").extract()
        info_Publikationsdatum = info.xpath(".//article/footer[@class='inseratfooter']/p[1]/strong/text()").extract_first()

        yield {'Titel': info_Titel,
        'Berufsfelder': info_Berufsfelder,
        'Arbeitspensum': info_Arbeitspensum,
        'Anstellungsverhältnis': info_Anstellungsverhältnis,
        'Arbeitsort': info_Arbeitsort,
        'VerfügbarAb': info_VerfügbarAb,
        'Kompetenzenqualifikation': info_Kompetenzenqualifikation,
        'Aufgabengebiet': info_Aufgabengebiet,
        'Erwartungen': info_Erwartungen,
        'WirBietenIhnen': info_WirBietenIhnen,
        'Publikationsdatum': info_Publikationsdatum}
```